# Compiling ijkplayer x264 for android x86 & x86_64 Architecture , error: unknown type name 'v4si'

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, x264, libx264

I'm trying to build this project
https://github.com/simplepeng/ijkplayer-x264
but building x264 failing for x86 and x86_64 architectures .
Link of the issue : https://github.com/simplepeng/ijkplayer-x264/issues/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use mix of different architectures for configure and compilation with options:

`--cross-prefix=i686-linux-android- --host=arm-linux`

In result configure thinks that you compiles for ARM platform but make use i686-linux-android-gcc for cross compilation. You should use:

`--cross-prefix=i686-linux-android- --host=i686-linux-android`